# Axis intersection - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want the graph below, in which there are negative values, to have the horizontal axis crossing the vertical one at 0. I have followed other posts that said to use the `expand` command, but that is not working for some reason.

```
diff_votos <- structure(list(Grupo = c("Controle", "Tratado"), 
                             N = c(32271L, 7623L), 
                             diff_media = c(-0.3541 -0.4072), 
                             diff_sd = c(2.0513, 1.6324), 
                             Erro_padrao = c(0.0216, 0.0355)), 
                        .Names = c("Grupo", "N", 
                                   "diff_media", "diff_sd", "Erro_padrao"), 
                        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -2L))


ggplot(diff_votos, aes(x = Grupo, 
                       y = diff_media)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), 
           stat = 'identity',
           colour = 'black',
           width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = diff_media - Erro_padrao,
                    ymax = diff_media + Erro_padrao),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                width = 0.4,
                size = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  labs(x = 'Grupo', y = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-0.6,0.6)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: You could do something like this: `scale_x_discrete(position="top") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-0.8, 0)) + theme_classic()`. The first statement puts the x axis on top of the graph. In the second statement, `limits=c(-0.8, 0)` sets the y-axis range; `expand(0,0)` removes padding at the ends that ggplot would otherwise put there by default, resulting in the x axis crossing exactly at y=0.

Comment: @eipi10 it improved my situation. However, is there a way I could change the limits of the axis to something like between -0.6 and 0.6. I have tried, but then the intersection would not be where I desire.

Comment: @eipi10 I have kind of found a solution... consisting of adding a horizontal line at y=0.